# list the tables in a database

Tags: java, sql, ms-access, jdbc, ucanaccess

Trying to get a list of all the tables in the .accdb database (2007-2016 format). Can't seem to find the MSysObjects table. Using UCanAccess

```
sql = "SELECT Name FROM MSysObjects WHERE Type = 1 AND Flags = 0";
ResultSet rs = queryChem(sql);

public static ResultSet queryChem(String sql) throws SQLException {
    Statement sChem = connChem.createStatement();
    ResultSet rsChem = sChem.executeQuery(sql);
    return rsChem;
}

private static void connectChem() {
    try {

        Class.forName("net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessDriver");
        System.out.println("Driver loaded");

        String url = "jdbc:ucanaccess://chemdb.accdb";
        connChem = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        System.out.println("Database Connected - CHEMS");

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
}
```

net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::3.0.6 user lacks privilege or object not found: MSYSOBJECTS
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessStatement.executeQuery(UcanaccessStatement.java:211)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to hit the [MSysObjects] table. You can get a list of tables via the `DatabaseMetaData#getTables` method, e.g.,

```java
try (ResultSet rsMD = connChem.getMetaData().getTables(null, null, null, null)) {
    while (rsMD.next()) {
        String tblName = rsMD.getString("TABLE_NAME");
        System.out.println(tblName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks
Exact code that worked was
    rs = connChem.getMetaData().getTables(null, null, "%", null);
    while (rs.next()) {
                String id = rs.getString(3);
            }